# Parse UTF-8 in Erlang R15

Tags: unicode, erlang

Erlang R15!

I have a UTF-8 encoded binary. I need to parse it to the unicode string (list). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: the unicode library is still available for R15!

Answer (score 6):

The unicode lib will help you.

```
Bin = <<"Hello">>.
unicode:characters_to_list(Bin, utf8).
```

Best practice for avoiding encoding troubles in Erlang:

**Always handle utf8 data as binaries and Unicode data as Erlang lists**

This best practice will make your life easier. It is very handy to follow this rule because it makes the usage of the available Erlang modules for unicode handling smooth.

And here are some more nice shell tools to use when debugging encoding problems:

Force the Erlang shell to print characters (a list of numbers):

```
io:put_chars([229,228,246]).
åäö
```

Note: This Will be printed with the shell encoding, so make sure your shell has the encoding you want to see the result in.

Force the Elrang shell to print numbers:

```
io:format("~w~n", ["åäö"]).
[229,228,246]
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the unicode translation modifier ?

```
io:format("~ts", [Binary]).
```

This does not result in a regular Erlang string, but that seems to be what you're looking after, no ?

Answer (score 1):

unicode:characteres_to_list(Binary).

Example:

```
> X = unicode:characters_to_binary("á").
  <<"á"/utf8>>
> unicode:characters_to_list(X).
  "á"
```